# What is the padding scheme for the original Tiger hash?

Tags: hash, reference-request

The [specification](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Tiger/tiger/node3.html#SECTION00030000000000000000) doesn't seem to indicate how to pad messages to the requisite 512-bit boundary.

What is the padding scheme for the original Tiger hash?

Answer (score 1):

> For drop-in compatibility, we adopt the outer structure of the MD4 family: the message is padded by a single '1' bit followed by a string of '0's and finally the message length as a 64-bit word. The result is divided into n 512-bit blocks.

http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~biham/Reports/Tiger/tiger/node2.html

I assume this 64 bit word is little endian, like the rest of Tiger and like the MD4 padding.

---

For reference the [RFC1320](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1320.txt) which describes MD4 says:

> a sequence of
>      bytes can be interpreted as a sequence of 32-bit words, where each
>      consecutive group of four bytes is interpreted as a word with the
>      low-order (least significant) byte given first.
>
> [...]
>
> **Step 1. Append Padding Bits**
>
> The message is "padded" (extended) so that its length (in bits) is
>      congruent to 448, modulo 512. That is, the message is extended so
>      that it is just 64 bits shy of being a multiple of 512 bits long.
>      Padding is always performed, even if the length of the message is
>      already congruent to 448, modulo 512.
>
> Padding is performed as follows: a single "1" bit is appended to the
>      message, and then "0" bits are appended so that the length in bits of
>      the padded message becomes congruent to 448, modulo 512. In all, at
>      least one bit and at most 512 bits are appended.
>
> **Step 2. Append Length**
>
> A 64-bit representation of b (the length of the message before the
>      padding bits were added) is appended to the result of the previous
>      step. In the unlikely event that b is greater than 2^64, then only
>      the low-order 64 bits of b are used. (These bits are appended as two
>      32-bit words and appended low-order word first in accordance with the
>      previous conventions.)
>
> At this point the resulting message (after padding with bits and with
>      b) has a length that is an exact multiple of 512 bits. Equivalently,
>      this message has a length that is an exact multiple of 16 (32-bit)
>      words. Let M[0 ... N-1] denote the words of the resulting message,
>      where N is a multiple of 16.